# Listing out binary combinations and mapping to data

Tags: python, list

Just started trying my hand at python and need some pointers.

I am looking to generate a combination based on certain parameters.

Basically,

```
parm1 = ['X1','X2']
parm2 = ['Y1','Y2']
```

What I'd like to get from this is

```
['X1','Y1','X1','Y1']
['X1','Y1','X1','Y2']
['X1','Y1','X2','Y1']
['X1','Y1','X2','Y2']
```

I thought one could use a binary list (itertools.product("01", repeat=4)) and substitute each element ie.

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
```

Would represent

```
X1 Y1 X1 Y1
X1 Y1 X1 Y2
```

What is the optimal way of doing this?

EDIT: Let me try and add more information.

```
Colour = ['Black','White']
Type = ['Car','Bike']
```

So, I'm trying to format this into the following

```
                       ('Colour','Type','Colour','Type')
('0', '0', '0', '0')-->('Black','Car','Black','Car')
('0', '0', '0', '1')-->('Black','Car','Black','Bike')
('0', '0', '1', '0')-->('Black','Car','White','Car')
('0', '0', '1', '1')-->('Black','Car','White','Bike')
('0', '1', '0', '0')
('0', '1', '0', '1')
('0', '1', '1', '0')
('0', '1', '1', '1')
('1', '0', '0', '0')
('1', '0', '0', '1')
('1', '0', '1', '0')
('1', '0', '1', '1')
('1', '1', '0', '0')
('1', '1', '0', '1')
('1', '1', '1', '0')
('1', '1', '1', '1')-->('White','Bike','White','Bike')
```

I know this can be done with an if statement for each index of the list but is there an alternative method?

EDIT AGAIN:

I wrote this, but think there much be a much more elegant solution?

```
import itertools
q=[]
x=["","","",""]
q=list(itertools.product("01", repeat=4))
for p in q:
    if float(p[0]) == 0:
        x[0]= "Black"
    else:
        x[0] = "White"
    if float(p[1]) == 0:
        x[1]= "Car"
    else:
        x[1] = "Bike"
    if float(p[2]) == 0:
        x[2]= "Black"
    else:
        x[2] = "White"
    if float (p[3]) == 0:
        x[3] = "Car"
    else:
        x[3] = "Bike"
    print p
    print x
```

Comment: Is there rule for selection some combinations?

Comment: Can you explain a little better how you get from parm1 and parm2 to the output lists you're requesting?

Comment: The four you've listed are given by `list(itertools.product(parm1, parm2, parm1, parm2))[:4]`, but I don't know if you only listed the first four you wanted and simply didn't mention that you wanted more, or if those are the only four you want and I don't understand the selection rule.

Comment: perhaps you'd like to give another example of inputs and outputs you require?

Comment: Added some more information, hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want is a flat version of this:

```
from itertools import product
nested = product(product(Colour, Type), repeat=2)
print list(nested)
# [(('Black', 'Car'), ('Black', 'Car')), 
#  (('Black', 'Car'), ('Black', 'Bike')),
#  ...
# ]
```

So here you go:

```
from itertools import product
nested = product(product(Colour, Type), repeat=2)

# flatten it by unpacking each element
print [(a,b,c,d) for ((a,b),(c,d)) in nested]

# alternative way to flatten the product
from itertools import chain
print [tuple(chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in nested]
```

To convert the `(0,1)` list you can use the numbers as indices:

```
from itertools import product

Colour = ['Black','White'] # so Color[0] == 'Black' 
Type = ['Car','Bike']

#make that list
nested = product((0,1), repeat=4) # use numbers not strings
print [(Colour[a], Type[b], Colour[c], Type[d]) for (a,b,c,d) in nested]
```

Comment: I might use `[tuple(chain(*p)) for p in nested]` or `chain.from_iterable` or something; seems a shame to use `repeat` to avoid hardcoding and then reintroduce it at the end.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at `nested = product(product(Colour, Type), repeat=2))`

Comment: Silly me, figured it out, `itertools.product`

Comment: @Ash: I had a extra `)` in there, try again

Comment: @JochenRitzel Yep! Understood it better now! :) I know this is the right solution, but to gain some know how, how does one map the 1s and 0s like I tried?

Comment: Do you mean to get from `(0,0,1,1)` to `('Black','Car','White','Bike')` ?

Comment: Btw, your code does not work because you compare `"0"` (string) with `0` (number)

Comment: Yep, that conversion. Hmm, it works here, I copied the output.

Comment: It outputs `['White', 'Bike', 'White', 'Bike']` every time.

Comment: Oops, it should be `if float(p[0]) == 0` But isn't there a more elegant solution?